# If I create a branch in Git, is it ok to merge the parent branch back into my working branch?

Tags: git

If I create a branch in Git, is it always ok to merge the parent branch back into my working branch, in order to collect changes that other people have checked in?

Let's say I start with a `master` and `feature` branch.

If I have `feature` checked out and I create a new branch:

```
feature> git checkout -b moreFeatureWork
```

Then, if I commit all my changes and merge my work into feature:

```
moreFeatureWork> git commit -a -m "Commit my changes"
feature> git merge --no-ff moreFeatureWork
```

Then, lets say I needed to do more week on that branch next week.  I let it sit for a week and in the meantime, lots of other people have merged their work into `feature`.

Is it ok to do this , to update my branch with the latest changes?

```
moreFeatureWork> git merge feature
```

Or, would that be problematic?

Comment: Yes, sure. Why are there any doubts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you didn't modify your `moreFeatureWork` branch? You just want to get 'up to date' before you start working?

If all goes well and people only added stuff on top of your `feature` branch, your suggested merge should only do a fast-forward and keep `moreFeatureWork` up to date.

Personally however, I would prefer a `moreFeatureWork> git rebase feature`
That way, you can potentially even update your `moreFeatureWork` branch when you have done some changes on it.

Note: assuming that your `moreFeatureWork` branch was merged completely into `feature` before, you could of course simply delete that branch and create a new branch.

```
feature> git branch -d moreFeatureWork
feature> git checkout -b moreFeatureWork2
```

branch or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a relatively common practice for developers that are working on a long-running feature, but need to keep in line with changes coming from upstream.

There shouldn't be any problems (save for a merge conflict or two if you and someone else was working in the same space) if you do this.

If you want to keep the history clean, you should elect to `rebase` that branch on top of yours instead:

```
git rebase <feature>
```

You may get merge conflicts, but they would be no different than if you had merged the two branches in.

Comment: I never used rebase before.   Thanks for highlighting that possibility for me.  :-)

Comment: Note, for many projects, you are *required* to perform a rebase before making a pull request.

Comment: @o11c:  That's the first time I've heard of those requirements.  Then again, other teams/development processes have their particulars.